# Accessing vue model data in nested method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In the simple example below I am calling my cloud service method within my vue model on page load, which contains an inner service specific lifecycle event `afterSubmitContacts()` which executes when the user carries out some event. Once the user carries out this event, the alert box pops up with `undefined` instead of `myTest`.

With the example below, my goal is to access vue model methods and data properties, successfully rather than getting undefined. What is the proper way of accessing vue model data and methods in the scenario below?

Thanks in advance!

```
            new Vue({
                el: '#vue-test',
                data: {
                    name: 'myTest',
                },
                template: '<a href="#" class="button btn-lg btn-primary">Button</a>',
                methods: {
                    initCloudService(event) {
                        cloudservice.init({
                            afterSubmitContacts: function (contacts) {
                                alert(this.name); //undefined
                                ...
                    }
                },
                ready() {
                    this.initCloudService();
                }
```

Comment: You can either use an arrow function for `afterSubmitContacts` e.g. `afterSubmitContacts: contact => alert(this.name)` or provision a reference to the expected value of `this` outside of that function and then reference the Vue instance through that e.g. `var self = this; afterSubmitContacts: function(contacts) { alert(self.name); }`. Obviously the former is preferred if you have the ability to use arrow functions in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the help Marty. Can you please post this comment as an answer? The second suggestion worked like a charm. I'd like to get the first suggestion working as well, although im getting a compile time error. Assuming theres more to the method body than just an alert and theres more than one argument, can you show a simple example on how the arrow function example would work? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You lost the context, your `this` refers to the function itself and not the Vue instance.

You can choose to:

1. Call a VueJS method >

```
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-test',
    data: {
      name: 'myTest',
    },
    template: '<a href="#" class="button btn-lg btn-primary">Button</a>',
    methods: {
      afterSubmitContacts(contacts) {
        alert(this.name);
        // ...
      },
      initCloudService(event) {
        cloudservice.init({afterSubmitContacts})
      }
    },
    ready() {
    this.initCloudService();
  }
}
```

2. Use arrow function instead >

```
afterSubmitContacts: contacts => {
    alert(this.name);
    // ...
}
```

3. Self is an ugly solution :)

Answer (score -1):

the problem here is that `afterSubmitContacts` holds a regular function. on execution, it binds the `this` based on several rules ([further reading here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)).

the code is not perfectly written (some closures are missing and how `afterSubmitContacts` is actually called), so i took some liberty with your code to pass the point.

**ES5 Solution**

```
new Vue({
            el: '#vue-test',
            data: {
                name: 'myTest',
            },
            template: '<a href="#" class="button btn-lg btn-primary">Button</a>',
            methods: {
                initCloudService(event) {
                    self=this;
                    cloudservice.init({
                        afterSubmitContacts: function (contacts) {
                            alert(self.name);
                        }
                    })
                }
            },
            ready() {
                this.initCloudService();
            }
        }
```

**ES6 Solution**

Arrow functions does not change the `this`, so you can still use it normally.

```
new Vue({
            el: '#vue-test',
            data: {
                name: 'myTest',
            },
            template: '<a href="#" class="button btn-lg btn-primary">Button</a>',
            methods: {
                initCloudService(event) {
                    cloudservice.init({
                        afterSubmitContacts: (contacts)=> {
                            alert(this.name);
                        }
                    })
                }
            },
            ready() {
                this.initCloudService();
            }
        }
```